# How to detect if the collection was modified during iteration

Tags: c#, collections, iteration

When iterating over a dictionary or a list or some other collection, can I somehow check if the collection was modified?

```cs
foreach (var pair in dictionary) {
   DoStuff(pair);
   if (DictionaryWasModified())
      break;
}
```

If `DoStuff` add to/removes from the dictionary, an exception will be raised on next iteration step. I want to avoid the exception.

Comment: The collections typically check this themselves, e.g. https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,940

Comment: see edit for clarification

Comment: I think you can avoid the exception by using a `for` loop instead of `foreach`

Comment: I can't if it's a dictionary.

Comment: By modify do you mean add/remove entries in the dictionary? Or do you mean change existing dictionary item values? Or both?

Comment: It sounds a lot like you're writing to the dictionary in one thread, and reading from it in another thread? **DO NOT DO THIS!** Dictionary is **NOT** thread-safe, and you will get some very strange (and even crashy) behaviour!

Comment: I mean adding/removing entries in the dictionary.  The actual code is single threaded and a lot more complex. I can deal with "No" as an answer, I'm not looking for alternative solutions.

Comment: @Markonius can you modify `DoStuff` to return whether the dictionary was modified?

Comment: Maybe, if the answer to my question is "no" I'll need to spend more time on changes to the code. Thanks for trying, anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dictionary, and it's iterator, keep the information about whether the collection has changed since the last iteration private, so you can't access it.  If you want to be able to iterate over a collection safely while it's being mutated, or be able to know when if it has changed since you started iteration, you'd need to make your own collection (presumably wrapping an existing collection) in which you keep track yourself whether or not it has changed, and expose that information publicly.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question and requires a modification to the `DoStuff` method to call your own wrapper collection so that it can track whether something has changed.

Comment: @ZaidMasud It does answer the question.  The question asks if you can tell if a dictionary has been modified.  The answer is you can't, although you can make a collection that will expose that information.

Comment: I mean that your wrapper collection idea doesn't even solve the problem. In addition to adding complexity, it requires changes to the `DoStuff` method, and it's not even clear how the wrapper collection will detect when to start tracking for changes.

Comment: @ZaidMasud It may or may not be suitable for them as an alternative.  It depends on whether or not they're in a position to use their own custom collection.  That doesn't change the fact that the answer to the question is that you can't use `Dictionary`.  Maybe they can use a custom collection, maybe they can't do either, either way, they can't use `Dictionary`.

Answer (score 1):

The collection in question holds a version information as initializing, then, as carrying some operations such as adding, removing, sorting etc. out, it increases version by one so that it can detect whether it is in an iteration. It can be examined over [its source code](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/51cf7850defa8a17d815b4700b67116e3fa283c2/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs#L1172). However, there is an exception IIRC that as of .NET Core 3.0 with C# 8.0, a dictionary may be modified during enumeration (foreach) via `.Remove` and `.Clear` only. This does not apply to other collections.